# Dice notation for excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

same question as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260344/dice-notation-in-excel-advanced-mode

I was advised to ask here too. so i do.

I asked if someone could make me a "User Defined Function" for excell that you calculate an equation expressed in dice notation (for rpg. like 1d6+3)

Here's the result (and it work really well) dice notation in excel

Now, i need three more functions.

1) RollMax(A1) that would give the max value of A1 (if A1 = 1d6+3, the result would be 9)

2) RollMin(A1) that would give the min value of A1 (if A1 = 1d6+3, the result would be 4)

3) RollAve(A1) that would give the average value of A1 (if A1 = 1d6+3, the result would be 6)

I need it in the same way as the Rolldice() made by Gary's in the linked post. It will be used by players that know nbothing in excel and i want it as seemless as possible. (RollDice() explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253155/dice-notation-in-excel )

Thanks a lot

best regards

## Edit 1 :

Dim allocate space to create a variable? Saying to the program "i'll be using these function/variables, keep a undefined space for them" ?

what does Deemode do exactly?

what does r.Value does ?

## Edit : 2

thanks for the answers.
i'm working on it

Comment: We are nto a free coding service!  If you try and actually make an effort, we will be willing to help, but you have to at least try

Comment: actually, that how superuser was sold to me. One person told me to ask here. Because i'm no coder, at all and thus need the help of one who knows.

" If you try and actually make an effort, we will be willing to help"

I did. i failed, that's why i ask.

Why do you assume that i didn't even tried?

Comment: If you made a serious effort, I think your question would be along the lines of "I tried this and that, but line x or function y doesn't do what I expect it to do". Now it really looks like 'please give me code to do this'.

Comment: I assumed because (before your question was edited) you were asking for someone to give you code to do something without you having shown any effort.  We unfortunately get people on here pretty much every day asking for us to just give them working code and we always ask them to try and then we will aid in debugging

Comment: when i was given the code for RollDice(), the first thing i did was to look into the code, to see its logic and how it works.

I have some base in lua (doing coding in computercraft) and very few notions of C.

It is way above my level. I'm not patient, i need this now, not in two month when i have catched all the things i need to do it by myself.

That's why i'm asking. that's how i train myselft.

On the other hand, if i was give the three function, i could reverse engineer them along with the RooDice() to see how its logic work and how to do it by myself (or even better, improve it)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You may want to take a minute to read [ask] and [help] to better understand how this site works. Everyone here helps for free with what experience we have. There is no *"I need it now"*. However, there is a reasonable expectation the person asking the question has attempted to solve the problem themselves. We are asking you to clarify what you've done and where you've gotten stuck so we know how best to help you. If you choose not to provide those details, you will likely not receive much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to repost the code from Gary's Student here with some additional comments on it.

The easiest way to see what is going on is to put a code break in the press F9 on a line near the beginning and step through it using the F9 key.  I would add a watch to the NewForm string which is building up your function

```
Public Function RollDice(r As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Dim v As String, NewForm As String, deemode As Boolean
    Dim dee As String
    dee = "d"
    deemode = False
        v = r.Value
        NewForm = "="
        For i = 1 To Len(v)
            ch = Mid(v, i, 1)
            'If the code finds a d it knows its a dice roll so it needs a randbetween function
            If ch = dee Then
                NewForm = NewForm & "*RANDBETWEEN(1,"
                deemode = True
            Else
            'If the character is a operator +-* then close the brackets of the rand between
                If Not IsNumeric(ch) And deemode Then
                    deemode = False
                    NewForm = NewForm & ")"
                End If
            'If the code doesn't find a d add that character to the end of the function
            NewForm = NewForm & ch
            End If
        Next i

        If deemode Then
            NewForm = NewForm & ")"
        End If

        RollDice = Evaluate(NewForm)

End Function
```

Now for example if you want a rollmax you need to change what it does when it finds a dice as you don't need a randetween function.  Have a go at the other two and post specific questions if you have problems instead of "write this code for me".

```
Public Function Rollmax(r As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Dim v As String, NewForm As String, deemode As Boolean
    Dim dee As String
    dee = "d"
    deemode = False
        v = r.Value
        NewForm = "="
        For i = 1 To Len(v)
            ch = Mid(v, i, 1)
            If ch = dee Then
                NewForm = NewForm & "*"
                deemode = True
            Else
                If Not IsNumeric(ch) And deemode Then
                    deemode = False
                    NewForm = NewForm & ""
                End If
                NewForm = NewForm & ch
            End If
        Next i


        Rollmax = Evaluate(NewForm)

End Function
```

EDIT:

Yes dim is declaring variables.  With variable declaration you can either start each one on a new line with dim or string them together with commas

what does Deemode do exactly? Deemode is a true false flag that is turned on when a "d" is found in the string.  It is turned off when it finds a non number (usually a +-*).

what does r.Value does ? r is a reference to a cell.  r.value returns the value of that cell (in this case the dice string).

Comment: that is exactly what i want. I'll do the rest by myself.

Thanks a lot.

best regards :)

Comment: see edit 1 for some questions :)

Comment: Answers for your addition questions added.